# How to convert the response from Okhttp into inputstream

Tags: android, inputstream, okhttp

### CODE:

```
  public static String getRequestNoPayload(String urlString, String loginApi, String mUsername) throws Exception {
        Response response;
        try{
            client.setConnectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // connect timeout
            client.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    // socket timeout
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(urlString)
                    .addHeader("username",loginApi)
                    .addHeader("password",mUsername)
                    .build();

            response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        }catch(Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
        return response.body().string();
    }
```

**What i am trying to do:**
I am trying to convert `response.body()` into a `inputstream`. How to achieve this

Comment: what version of OkHttp do you use?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

you can get the InputStream through [byteStream()](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/index.html)

E.g.

```
 InputStream is = response.body().byteStream();
```

to return it you have to change the method's signature. From `String` to `InputStream`